# Path export is not working

Tags: macos, path

I'm trying to create a phonegap app but when i run `cordova platform add android`, I get the error:

```
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

/Users/chrisruno/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.
    at /Users/chrisruno/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:80:29
    at _fulfilled (/Users/chrisruno/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/chrisruno/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/chrisruno/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /Users/chrisruno/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/chrisruno/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:282:30
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I had run `brew install android-sdk` before hand.  I also ran `android` and it said I was already on 19.  I'm installing 20 and 4.3, 4.2, 4.1.2, and 4.0 now to see if that will meet some kind of dependency.

This is what my ~/.profile looks like:

`export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.6.2/tools:$PATH"`

I also tried it with just this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Eclipse/Android\ SDK/platform-tools:/Applications/Eclipse/Android\ SDK/tools
export PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to install those updates, install eclipse, and follow the steps here, http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html, for installing the ADT plugins.